# Show full post on front page?

Tags: nodes

When I publish to the front page, it shows part of the posts. My posts consist of just a file upload. However, the user must click on the post/click on the "Read more" button to see the file upload. How would I make Drupal display this file on the front page within the post?

Answer (score 7):

If you are using Drupal 7 you may change the teaser format for the content types promoted on front page. Navigate to "Home » Administration » Structure » Content types » YOUR CONTENT TYPE » Manage display" and click the "teaser" sub tab; then change the format for the body field from "Summary or trimmed" to "Default".

Notice that this will affect some other pages (taxonomy and views).

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

I would replace the frontpage with a view provided by the [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) module; there is even a default View that comes with the module. Initially, it emulates the standard frontpage, but is far more configurable. I can't post a full "How to use Views" answer here, but in short, what you will want to add is a "Field", pick the "File" category, and there you can output a direct link to the file.

[Video series about using Views](http://dev.nodeone.se/en/taming-the-beast-learn-views-with-nodeone).

Answer (score 0):

ya.teck and kiamlaluno are correct except that you may not see a "teaser" tab. If this is the case, then be sure to check the custom display options for your content type and activate "teaser" - it should be one of the check boxes available. Then save the content type and you should then see the teaser tab/button mentioned above.